# Unknown geometry type in postgis on ST_contains

Tags: postgis

I am trying to match a geometry of type Polygon to Point using ST_Contains:

```
UPDATE events
SET country = countries.geonameid
FROM countries
WHERE ST_Contains(countries.geometry, events.location)
```

The country table was created as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE countries (
    geonameid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    geometry GEOMETRY(Geometry, 4326)
)
INSERT INTO countries (geonameid, geometry VALUES (%s, ST_GeometryFromText(%s, 4326)))
```

and the event table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE events
(
    id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
    location GEOMETRY(Point, 4326),
    country INT
)
INSERT INTO events (id, location) VALUES (%s, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(%s %s)', 4326)) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING"
```

Unfortunately on the update query I obtain the following error:

> psycopg2.InternalError: Unknown geometry type: -671088639 - Point

Comment: There's a syntax error with `GEOMETRY(Geometry, 4326})`. I suggest using a more specific geometry type, such as `geometry(MultiPolygon, 4326)`

Comment: Also, the coordinate you are trying to INSERT doesn't look like the dd.ddddd format.